# Turn spreadsheet into web page for multiple users simultaneously

Tags: web, spreadsheet, multiple-users

I have created an excel spreadsheet with many calculations depending on number that a user inserts in every row.
I would like to turn it into web page so multiple users could access it simultaneously. I believe I can't do it with MySQL, because, although it supports multiple users, it can't use all of the functions that already exist in the spreadsheet. Those functions and calculations depend on value cells of not only the active row, but previous and next rows also.
I don't want to use (free-trial or free) applications and programs that convert it in minutes to web page, but I would like to do it all by myself.
Which programming language is the best?
I repeat that the goal is to be used by multiple users.
Thanks in advance